# Define a relation R on Z × N by (a, α)R(b, β) if and only if aβ = bα. Prove that R is a reflexive relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm a bit confused about how to prove that R is reflexive.

By definition, R, a relation in a set S, is reflexive if and only if ∀x∈S, xRx.

Since (a, α)R(b, β), we know that aβ = bα.

Then to prove that this is reflexive, based on the definition, we would have to show that ((a, α)R(b, β)) R ((a, α)R(b, β). After this, I'm not sure as to how to prove why this is reflexive.

Could we possibly do something like (aβ = bα) R (aβ = bα) is reflexive? Or does ((a, α)R(b, β)) R ((a, α)R(b, β)) already show that it is reflexive itself?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $R$ is reflexive is to prove that, for each $(a,\alpha)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb N$, $(a,\alpha)\mathrel R(a,\alpha)$. But $(a,\alpha)\mathrel R(a,\alpha)$ means that $a\alpha=a\alpha$, and it is clear that this holds.

Comment: Oh, I see so I don't use it as ((a, α)R(b, β)) R ((a, α)R(b, β). Could I also prove that this is reflexive by using (b, β) R (b, β)? So in this case, to prove that R is reflexive is to prove that, for each (b, β) ∈ Z×N, (b, β) R (b, β).  Since (b, β) R (b, β) means that bβ = bβ, R is reflexive. @José

Comment: Yes, you can use $(b\,beta)$. Or $(h,\theta)$. Or $(\zeta,\aleph)$. Or any pair of letters you want.

Comment: But in this problem, (h,θ) or (ζ,ℵ)would be irrelevant to this problem right? Thank you for all the help! @José

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hi professor Santos, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695457/if-q-is-a-rectangle-and-if-d-subseteq-q-is-the-set-of-points-where-fq-righ)?